# Jquery onclick not working for dynamic class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a tag :

```
<p class="link show"><p>
```

```js
$('.show').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass( "show" ).addClass( "hide" );
});   

$(".hide").on("click", function(){
    alert('Clicked...');
});
```

The `show` class removes and `hide` class adds successfully, **But onclick is not working for `hide` class**.

What am i missing ?

Comment: `$(document).on('click' , '.hide' , function(){})`

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef its not working for it.

Comment: You need to use delegated event handlers as you're changing the classes you hook to dynamically at runtime. See the duplicate I marked above

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Its quite wired, The answers not working either in your duplicate mark.

Comment: Yes it does: http://jsfiddle.net/6275mgeb/